# How to install and use keras on M1 Macbook pro

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, miniconda

I want to try to use Keras on my Macbook M1 using a pre-trained model, but it doesn't seem to work. I took a look at some other tutorials and even StackOverflow questions using miniconda, but I'm not sure where to start. Please also point out any errors in my programming. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import model_from_json


# Load the pre-trained model
model = model_from_json(open("facial_expression_model_structure.json", "r").read())
model.load_weights('facial_expression_model_weights.h5')

# Define the emotions
emotions = ('angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise', 'neutral')

# Open a connection to the webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture a frame from the webcam
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert the frame to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces in the frame using a Haar Cascade classifier
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    # For each detected face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        # Draw a rectangle around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        # Extract the region of interest (ROI) from the grayscale image
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        # Resize the ROI to match the input size of the model
        roi = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48))
        roi = roi.astype('float32')
        roi /= 255
        roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)
        roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=-1)

        # Make a prediction using the pre-trained model
        prediction = model.predict(roi)[0]

        # Find the emotion with the highest probability
        max_index = np.argmax(prediction)
        emotion = emotions[max_index]

        # Display the emotion on the image
        cv2.putText(frame, emotion, (x + 20, y - 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame with detected faces and emotions
    cv2.imshow('Emotion Detection', frame)

    # Exit the loop when 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the webcam and close all OpenCV windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also it would be preferable if I could get it to work in PyCharm

Comment: You need to be very specific about "it doesn't seem to work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install miniforge from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge3

Create a new environment with Python 3.8 or higher, for example:

```
conda create -n kerasenv python=3.8
```

Activate the environment:

```
conda activate kerasenv
```

Install TensorFlow:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps

pip install tensorflow-macos
```

Install Keras:

```
pip install keras
```